# How to check if id contains multiple words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div:

```
<div id="picture_contents_12356_title"></div>
```

The '12356' is a unique id that is auto-generated and I need to have it there. How can I create a jQuery selector for an id that has "picture_contents" AND "title"?

I know you can do `[id*="picture_contents"]` but I also need to check if it contains "title" as well. How do I do create the AND logic there?

I was thinking maybe extracting the id into a variable and checking `indexOf("picture_contents")` and `indexOf("title")` but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: `$('[id*="picture_contents"][id*="title"]')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just keep adding attribute based selectors `[attribute*=".."]`

In your case,

```
$('[id*="picture_contents"][id*="title"]')
```

> *Suggestion:* if the pattern of words is constant, you could use `^=` : starts-with or `$=`: ends-with selector too.

---

For,

```
<div id="picture_contents_12356_title"></div>
```

Use,

```
$('[id^="picture_contents"][id$="title"]')
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does the *= operator work like a "contains"?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could concatenate id selectors like that to form an AND logic.

Comment: @Alistair: Yep, it works because an attribute selector is just like an ID selector, a class selector or a pseudo-class. You can mix and match any combination of these as long as the element will match all of them. Just be careful not to be overly specific. In this case it's OK because there is no other solution without changing the markup (or whatever is generating it).

Comment: I second @BoltClock here. A better practice would be to group the elements needed by a unique attribute. The above code is difficult to maintain as the structure of IDs might change anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could give all of the appropriate divs a class and refer to that instead.